# Invert selection on QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview, selectionmodel, qmodelindex

I have a QListView and I have already set a model to it. How can I implement a method for invert selection?

I have already tried making a new `QItemSelection` that contains all the items of my model in order to call `ui.listView->selectionModel()->select(selection, QItemSelectionModel::Toggle);` but my `QItemSelection` returns empty.

I have also thought of using the same method for each QModelIndex of my model, but I found no way to get a list of all `QModelIndex` of my  model.

Any ideas?

Comment: anyone please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. It is all about understanding `QModelIndex` and not asking the model for its items. First thing is to get the `QModelIndex` that is the root of the current level/branch of the `QListView` and then get the `QModelIndex`s of the first and last children of this root `QModelIndex`.
After that you can easily create a new `QItemSelection` that contains every child of this root.
Finally you use this `QItemSelection` to toggle the selection-model of the `QListView`.

```
void BrowserWidget::invertSelection() {
    QModelIndex rootIndex = ui.listView->rootIndex();
    QModelIndex first = rootIndex.child(0, 0);
    int numOfItems = m_itemsModel->rowCount(rootIndex);
    QModelIndex last = rootIndex.child(numOfItems - 1, 0);

    QItemSelection selection(first, last);
    ui.listView->selectionModel()->select(selection, QItemSelectionModel::Toggle);
}
```